# dc.js brush chart reference via div id possible?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

js with Vue.js. In my example The brush chart and the target chart are in different child components this makes the data communication a bit hard.
But i could address the div easily via the DOM. Is it possible to address the target charts via their id?

Comment: I think you are referring to range/focus charts and the `rangeChart` configuration, which takes a reference to another chart instance. Sorry, there is no way to get a chart reference from a selector. [react-dc-js](https://github.com/dc-js/react-dc-js) handles this with a context component further up in the component hierarchy that handles the association between ids and charts. Maybe overengineered for your purpose, and I don't know what the equivalent Vue construct is, just thought I'd throw it out there.